# dynamically place file in s3 when creating a new Model in Django

Tags: python, django, signals

When I create a new model "Truck" in Django one of my fields is a FileField which saves files to S3. I want to place this file in a folder that matches my model instance.

When I save a new instance of Truck, for instance "Red Truck" I want to upload the file to a folder in S3 called "Red Truck".

This is for keeping documentation neat at my company.

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify


class Truck(models.Model):
    @staticmethod
    def pre_save(sender,instance,**kwargs):
        s3_truck_name = self.truck_number

    truck_number = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    vin = models.CharField(max_length=17)
    registration = models.FileField(upload_to=f'trucks/{s3_truck_name}')
    cab_card = models.FileField(upload_to=f'trucks/{s3_truck_name}')
    title = models.FileField(upload_to=f'trucks/{s3_truck_name}')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Truck: {self.truck_number}'

pre_save.connect(Truck.pre_save, Truck)




NameError: name 's3_truck_name' is not defined
```

Comment: Found the solution! It was in Django FileField docs:
`def user_directory_path(instance, filename):
    # file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/user_<id>/<filename>
    return 'user_{0}/{1}'.format(instance.user.id, filename)

class MyModel(models.Model):
    upload = models.FileField(upload_to=user_directory_path)`

Comment: Hello! You can also post an answer to your own question (and accept it after a period of time) so that it's easier to read for anyone else with similar problem stumbling by (...and for full-sized code blocks)

Answer (score 0):

```
def user_directory_path(instance, filename): 
#file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/user_<id>/<filename> 
return 'user_{0}/{1}'.format(instance.user.id, filename) 

class MyModel(models.Model): upload = models.FileField(upload_to=user_directory_path)
```